# Uneven Distribution in rand() ( C language )

Tags: c, random, distribution

I wanted to see if there is any way to generate random numbers with uneven distribution which I would like to customize.
for example:
In 100 generated numbers I would like to have :
10 A
20 B
40 C
10 D
15 E
5  F

And I wanted to say that I'm new to programming so try to help me with your simple answers.
Really Really Thank You.

Comment: Set the distribution required first, and then pick at random from that distribution. So build an array of 100 elements with 10 of A, 20 of B etc, and then index by `rand() % 100` (although there will be a small bias).

Comment: An easy way is to generate numbers from 0 to 99, and set the output as A from 0 to 9, B from 10 to 29 and so on

Comment: @B.Go: Brilliant, and easily understandable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Encoding used in many places, like encoding light colors (categories) from a digital fader always between 0 and 255

Comment: @kaylum doesn't seem completely related, and at least way too complex for this use case

Comment: @WeatherVane I had if/switch in mind, but your comment with an array should also work the same...

Comment: If you want exactly those counts, fill an array with the desired number of each outcome, shuffle it, and then iterate through the array.

Comment: @B.Go You'll need to make that numbers from 0 to 89, since the sum of the specified counts is 90, not 100.

Comment: @pjs which is true but strange when the OP wants to sort 100 numbers, and really looks like standard grades, also out of 100; I guess there should be 15 F

Comment: Lazy solution: `"AAAAAAAAAAB...(20)...C...30)..."` and then just take a random slice of that.

Comment: @B.Go Agreed, but no way to be sure without Alireza editing or commenting.

Comment: @pjs You're right!

Comment: Thank you guys! With your help I've found the right solution for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty simple, yet often highly effective solution for problems like this:

```
char *samples = "AABBCCDDEEFFFFF";

char randomSample() {
  return sample[rand() % strlen(samples)];
}
```

Comment: Thank You as well!